# Which one is better for a background task? foreground service or whitelist permission?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-service, whitelist

I am developing an application that monitors buses' icons on the google map and triggers a notification once they get close to the bus station. Everything works perfectly fine as long as the app is visible to the user. Right when the phone's screen is turned off, the app is no longer responsive to the runnable running in the background. I am aware of the doze mode and researched a lot on the web. Currently, I was able to overcome this by using a service in the foreground that binds to the application. However, this creates a notification in the status bar and might not be pleasant to the user. I have another option, ask the user to grant the permission to my app to be on the whitelist apps for battery optimization exempt. I want to know which one is better and are there other approaches that are working better in my situation? Please note that my app needs to get data from a server every 5 seconds, and this synchronization will not last long, maybe 30 minutes maximum, so I am not worried about battery drain.

Comment: Foreground service. Its high fidelity and accuracy are guaranteed. Whitelist is a bad idea since it involves user actions and your service may still be killed by the system.

Comment: @DeweyReed Thanks, I was thinking foreground service might be even lighter in terms of using resources compared to the UI thread since service classes do not use UI elements.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your meaning. Foreground service uses the main thread(UI thread) by default and you can use another thread if you want.

Comment: Yes, both of them use the main thread ( I did not know about that).  I did not use a new thread for my service class as I stop the runnable for the service class in the activity's onResume() method and use another runnable in my activity. On the other hand, in onPause() method, I stop my activity's runnable and start the runnable of the service class. I am hoping this is a right approach in terms of CPU usage and skipping the doze mode.

Comment: I haven't tried this approach yet so I'm not sure if it works. FYI, test your app on Android O or later because many background tasks have to be a foreground service to make things work.

Comment: It is working for me just fine. No bug or anything. Yes, I am aware of the aggressive doze mode in the android Oreo, thanks though.